# Order a list based on two different lists

Tags: python, list, sorting

What is the proper way to order elements in one list based on values of two (or more lists) in base Python. Say I have three lists:

```
X = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
Y = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1]
Z = [2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1]
```

I want to order the values of `X` first based on `Z` and then based on `Y`. The desired output would be:

```
["d", "h", "b", "i", "f", "a", "c", "e", "g"]
```

Comment: the way to order the elements is unclear to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply `zip` the lists and then use `sorted` plus unpacking:

```
>>> [i[2] for i in sorted(zip(Z, Y, X))]
['d', 'h', 'b', 'i', 'f', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'g']
```

By `zip`ping it with `Z` first and `Y` as second input it will give the desired order - and the outer comprehension discards the `Z` and `Y` again leaving you with the `X` values. Okay, in case both `Z` and `Y` are equal it will breaks ties by comparing the `X` (which could be undesired according to the question), you could disable that by using a custom `key` function that excludes `X`:

```
>>> [i[2] for i in sorted(zip(Z, Y, X), key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))]
['d', 'h', 'b', 'i', 'f', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'g']
```

Comment: This is probably simplest. Could also use `operator.itemgetter` in place of the lambda.

Comment: @Mitch That's correct, `key=operator.itemgetter(0, 1)` would also work. I often forget that `itemgetter` accepts multiple arguments.